# how to send email anonymous from Gmail

Tags: anonymity, ip-address, fingerprinting, openvpn, ip-address-leak

If I send email from gmail account using Tor browser with VPN connection can my identity be anonymous? can anyone find me out by tracking my email?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how this works.  Once you log into Google, you are no longer anonymous.

Comment: He thinks that VPN will scramble his IP address and Gmail won't be able to tell. and that email recipients will also see a scrambled IP in the email's header

Answer (score 4):

You can't. If you want to stay anonymous, you cannot send an email through Gmail as you will lose your anonymity. One of the main things not to do while using Tor is to use Google services since your emails are not private and can easily be read and traced. No email service is completely anonymous though there are certain email services which are more private than others. As an alternative, if you really have to send an email on the Tor browser (don't), use **Proton Mail**. It's definitely one of the most private email services and if you want to be anonymous, use this. If you want to only send one email or only receive one email, you should use **Guerilla Mail** since it's an anonymous disposable email service. You also should remember not to include any personal information or identifiable information in case the email is read and to use a VPN when sending. No email service is perfect at keeping you anonymous, but there are better ways to send emails on Tor than using Gmail.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stay anonymous, you need to think about every step when using your mail provider.

1. Registering your account
2. Accessing your mail account
3. Reading your mails
4. Writing your mails

You have to assume that your mail provider saves every step you do in your account. This seems especially true for GMail, but also it is also true for others.

So when you register for an account, you need to think about anonymity. I'd suggest that you use at least Tor Browser to register for an account. Using [tails](https://tails.boum.org/) might be even better. Sometimes provides want a phone number or some other identifying thing. Make sure that you have a number available which is not registered to your name.

Whenever you access your mail account you should use tails or Tor Browser.

When you want to write mails, you should use the web interface of the mail provider together with tails or Tor Browser. Don't use an external mail program like Thunderbird, Outlook or similar things. Those software might leak your real IP address. Some mail providers will include the IP address you used to log in in the mail. So everyone who receives the mail sees the IP address.

If you make those efforts, I'm pretty sure that you can send anonymous mails from any provider.